# Intermittently First Iteration fail but second iteration pass

Tags: perl, bash, ssh

The same command is failing in first iteration, but passing in second iteration. Sometime it is passing in both iterations. `$ssh` is the object of `Net::SSH::Expect`.
Any idea of this strange behavior?

```
$ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new(
                    host => "$host",
                    password => "$pass",
                    user => "$id",
                    raw_pty => 1,
                    timeout => 50
                    );
```

Code Snippet:

```
&Test("Create exports on Sonas------ No Kerberos");
$no_of_exports=2;
my $fs = "/ibm/gpfs0/";
while($no_of_exports)
{
    my $share_name = &get_share_name();
    my $path="$fs" . "$share_name";

    $cmd="ssh mgmt001st001 mkexport $share_name $path --nfs 'client002\\\\(rw,no_root_squash\\)'";
    print "CMD: $cmd";
    $out=$ssh->exec("$cmd");
    print $out;
    --$no_of_exports;
}
```

Output:

```
Test 02 : Create exports on *Sonas*------ No Kerberos

CMD: ssh mgmt001st001 mkexport kas41535108 /ibm/gpfs0/kas41535108 --nfs 'client002\\     (rw,no_root_squash\)'

--nfs 'client002\\(xport kas41535108 /ibm/gpfs0/kas41535108 
> rw,no_root_squash\)'
 bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 bash: -c: line 0: `mkexport kas41535108 /ibm/gpfs0/kas41535108 --nfs client002\\('
 [root@ganesha36 ~]# 
 [root@ganesha36 ~]# 
CMD: ssh mgmt001st001 mkexport kas219760489 /ibm/gpfs0/kas219760489 --nfs 'client002\\  (rw,no_root_squash\)'
89 --nfs 'client002\xport kas219760489 /ibm/gpfs0/kas2197604 
> \(rw,no_root_squash\)'
EFSSG0019I The export kas219760489 has been successfully created.
EFSSG1000I The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Are you instantiating your Net::SSH::Expect object in `raw_pty` mode?

Comment: yes added that part as well in my question now.

Comment: Why do you have `\\\\ ` before the parenthesis? Unless I'm missing something, that should be `\\ ` (without the spaces).

Comment: it is required to escape in multiple layer...check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616454/command-execution-is-failing-from-perl-script#comment15395363_11616454 for detail

Comment: I guess you did not understand what ikegami meant. You should have escaped the `*` but it is replaced by a client name now. So there is no need for `\\\\ `. And especially if you use `\\ ` for the corresponding bracket. Your code does not seem to match your output, too.. where do those spaces come from?

Comment: I tried by removing \\\\ and replaced with \\ for corresponding bracket. But it didn't work then. This escape sequence is making me crazy.  I tried to escaped by * with \\ that also didnt work. Why it is failing intermittently.

Comment: To understand what you are really getting on the remote end, replace your `mkexport` invocation with an `echo` of your single-quoted sting into `xxd` and look at the hex dump of what is received for any weird control characters. I also don't understand where the five spaces in a row are coming from in the captured failed scenario.

Comment: I've seen Net::SSH::Expect not fully close previous used sessions, then mysteriously fail the next time it is used.  You must remember to fully close them before exiting your script.  If you are having issues with character escaping/translations, then I recommend putting your commands into a script on the far end, then a smaller/simpler expect to run that script.

Comment: What happens if you increase the timeout `timeout` to 5x or 10x? If you change your loop index `no_of_exports` to run only once (rather than twice), and then manually run the script twice, does the same behavior result?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is right there.  Bash is choking because the `(` token is unexpected.  you need to add two more backslashes where you have four of them so

```
$cmd="ssh mgmt001st001 mkexport $share_name $path --nfs 'client002\\\\(rw,no_root_squash\\)'";
```

becomes

```
$cmd="ssh mgmt001st001 mkexport $share_name $path --nfs 'client002\\\\\\(rw,no_root_squash\\)'";
```